# What framework needs to be imported to use CGImage?

Tags: iphone, cgimage

So I have an app that gets pixel data from a picture and then manipulates to change brightness levels via RGB values of each pixel.

I have these lines of code to convert a `UIImage` to a `CGImage`:

```
CGDataProviderRef dataProvider = CGImageGetDataProvider(mycgImage);
CFDataRef imageData = CGDataProviderCopyData(dataProvider);
void *pixels = CFDataGetBytePtr(imageData);
```

I keep getting an error of

> "_CGImageGetDataProvder", referenced from: (blah blah blah)

and

> "_CGDataProviderCopyData", referenced from: (blah blah blah)

Can anyone tell me how to fix these errors? I've tried googling them, but to no avail. I think it has to do with me not importing something. Anyone got any help for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to import the CoreGraphics framework, and/or the QuartzCore framework. Right click on the Frameworks group and do "Add Existing Framework".

Comment: I imported the QuartzCore framework (but not the CoreGraphics framework). Could not importing both be giving me the error?

Comment: Got it to work by importing CoreGraphics! THanks! Best answer to you!